# I want to ask about a particular problem in flutter regarding data showing

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I was making A simple ebook representation I have made a List using ListView builder and a Grid using Grid using Gridview and i decoded data from the server using Api . The item used in both list and Grid are common Data fetched from server is easily shown in Grid but not in List I hope i can found a solution...
Note Same data is also used in grid and list via provider

```
//item used to create Grid`
import 'package:ebook_ui/ebook_detail.dart';

import './ebook_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class EbookItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  EbookItem(this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ebook = Provider.of<Ebooks>(context, listen: false);
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
        child: InkWell(
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
              placeholder: "assets/images/placeholder_box.jpg",
              image: ebook.imageslist[index],
              height: 170,
              width: 120,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(EbookDetail.routeName);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
//List of items code
import 'package:ebook_ui/ebook_item.dart';
import 'package:ebook_ui/ebook_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class EbookHorizontalList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ebooks = Provider.of<Ebooks>(context, listen: false);
    return SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
        child: Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
            itemCount: ebooks.imageslist.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return EbookItem(index);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Grid Code

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import './ebook_provider.dart';

import './ebook_item.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EbookGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  const EbookGrid({super.key});
  static const routeName = '/All_Ebooks';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ebook = Provider.of<Ebooks>(context, listen: false).imageslist;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Ebooks'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () async {},
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 15.0),
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.longestSide,
          child: GridView.builder(
              itemCount: ebook.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 0.0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
                  childAspectRatio: 3 / 5),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return EbookItem(index);
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **GridView** you have selected `itemCount: ebook.length` as the number of your items, however, for the **ListView** you are using `itemCount: ebooks.imageslist.length`. Maybe this is the problem. make sure that `ebooks.imageslist.length` is not equal to **0**.